# If there are several sets of radio buttons, browser pre-selects the option with the same value upon page reload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I had some difficulty in condensing the problem into a 1-line question so please bear with me. I have the following setup:

```
<form id="uploadform_11">
<input type="radio" id="v1_11" name="test_11" value="value1">
<input type="radio" id="v2_11" name="test_11" value="value2">
<input type="radio" id="v3_11" name="test_11" value="value3">
<input type="file" name="file_11" onchage="uploadFile()">
</form>
<form id="uploadform_12">
<input type="radio" id="v1_12" name="test_12" value="value1">
<input type="radio" id="v2_12" name="test_12" value="value2">
<input type="radio" id="v3_12" name="test_12" value="value3">
<input type="file" name="file12" onchage="uploadFile()">
</form>
...
```

So several upload forms, each with 3 radio buttons that have **identical values** in each form but **different names and ids**. Now, a user essentially selects a radio button from the "_11" series, and then selects a file to upload. The uploadFile is a javascript function which uploads the file through

```
function uploadFile() {
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( ... ); //here some form data incl the file name are appended
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
...
ajax.open("POST", "https://example.com/file_upload_parser.php"); // here the file upload happens
ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Once the upload has completed the completeHandler function is called:

```
function completeHandler(event) {
...
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 2000); // refresh page
}
```

**Now here is where the problem occurs**: say the user selects the radio button with id="v1_11" and then uploads the first file; once the page has reloaded, I no longer display the first form (uploadform_11) as the user already uploaded that file and there are only the remaining forms left (uploadform_12, uploadform_13, etc.). Now, on the reloaded page, in the next form (uploadform_12 in this case) the radio button with id="v1_12" is automatically selected in the browser. I do not understand why this happens. Alternatively, say the user selected id="v2_11" when uploading the first file, then id="v2_12" is selected upon reload, etc. I.e., upon reload the browser seems to pre-select the option from the next set of radio buttons that has the **same value** as was selected in the preceding file upload. If I have more than 2 sets of radio buttons then this preselection always occurs in the set that immediately follows the set that was clicked before.

Note: this behaviour **only occurs with a Firefox browser** (I am using the latest version v 94.0.1 64-bit on Win 10) but not with Chrome or Edge. Is this a bug in Firefox or is this perhaps expected behaviour?

Comment: Why would you reload the page if you use AJAX?

Comment: Also we would want to see the HTML and possible the "inspect" from your browser

Comment: @ why reload: I reload to refresh what is shown to the user. The upload is marked as "completed" in a db and the first upload form is removed.